# Mac OS soft link failure

Tags: vim

The establishment of dotfile management of.Vimrc file in the Github folder

```
Git clone dotfile files to ~
ln -s ~/dotfile/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
ln -s ~/dotfile/.vim ~/.vim
```

Then I input `vim` ,it display `".vimrc" [Permission Denied]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I setup my vim configuration:

Make a repository called dotfiles. Copy your `.vimrc` into this file and rename it to `vimrc`. Then copy all of the folders inside your `.vim` folder into the dotfiles repository. Now your dotfiles repo should contain a file called `vimrc` and possibly some other folders such as `ftplugin`, `bundle`... (all the folders that are inside your .vim).

Now whenever you want to clone your vim config onto another machine use

```
$ git clone reponame ~/.vim
```

So now you have cloned the repo into a new .vim folder. If you put the line `runtime vimrc` inside your real `.vimrc` file (in the home directory) everything will now work.

Comment: Thanks， it‘s OK.May I ask a question, why my vote is negative?

Comment: I'm not completely sure why you got negative votes but I would assume it is because your question did not provide much information about the problem, you just told us that your symlinks didn't work.